# Non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

> The non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function , x$\zeta(s)$ lies in the critical strip $0<\Re(s)<1$

> Riemann Hypothesis states that all the zeros of Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$ lies on the critical line , $\Re(s)=1/2$.

> G.H. Hardy proved that an infinity of zeros are on the critical line, $\Re(s)=1/2$

**Question** Are the number of non trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ in the critical strip but not on the critical line finite?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491324/are-the-nontrivial-zeroes-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-countable

Comment: @jojobo Thanks. But I am asking that the zeros not on the critical line but in the strip is finite or not?

Comment: In that case, this might help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161474/a-couple-of-facts-on-the-non-trivial-zeros-of-the-riemann-zeta-function

Comment: @jojobo Thanks. But answer to the first question in this post is not given

Comment: I`m sorry, you could take them as starting points for further research. Also it seems to be an open problem as mentioned in the comments of the second question.

Comment: We don't know if $\sup \Re(\rho)$ is $<1$.

Comment: @reuns What do you mean by that?

Comment: We know that no zero has real part $1$ but we don't know if a sequence of zeros has real part converging to $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do not know if there are finitely many ($0$ if RH is true) or infinitely many non-trivial zeros off the critical line. Showing that there are finitely many (not necessarily $0$) would be a huge breakthrough already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer